# A single reference not working

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Has anyone ever had a situation where a single reference is not working when using bibtex? I have a document that has over 100 references and for someone reason with two of the references I just get ?? when I try to use \cite{...} in the document. I have double checked that the formatting for these references is correct and I have no idea what could be causing the issue. For example, one of the references that is not working is

```
@book{GT,
    title={Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order},
    author={Gilbarg, D. and Trudinger, N.S.},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Springer}}
```

Comment: if you have cited GT and run bibtex either it will put an entry in the generated bibliography or it will give an error. The error may not be in this entry it could be in an earlier one affecting the parsing of the file, so if you do not show the bibtex log (`.blg`) or the latex log (`.log`) with the error messages it isn't really possible to help

Comment: I removed the biblatex tag and added bibtex as your title indicates you are usig bibtex not biblatex/biber

Comment: Ah true good point I moved the reference to the first one in the bibtex file and it worked but then other ones did not compile, so the error must be in one of the other ones affecting the parsing of the file

Comment: what does the blg file say?